# Convex n- sided polygon proof writing (homework question)

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, computer-science, convex-analysis, polygons

Would anyone be able to help me with the following problem or give me a push in the right direction? I am not entirely sure where to start and I have been looking at this problem for hours... Any help is appreciated.

Let n ≥ 3. Suppose an *n-* sided convex polygon is formed by taking *n* points on a circle,
and joining adjacent points by straight lines. A *diagonal* of such a polygon is a straight line between two corners, that is not one of the sides of the original polygon.

Prove that the maximum number of diagonals that can be drawn in such a convex *n-* sided
polygon, so that no two diagonals meet except at a corner, is n - 3.

Comment: Start small. What if $n=4$?

Comment: Last phrase: "is $~n\ge 3$" or "is $~n-3$" must be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote maximal number of such diagonals as $D(n)$.

For triangle it is obvious: it has $0$ diagonals: $D(3)=0$.

For quadrilateral it is obvious: it can has only $1$ diagonal: $D(4)=1$.

Now use **math. induction**.

Suppose that for any $n<n_0$ this statement is true: $D(n)=n-3$. 
Prove that this statement is true for $n=n_0$ (prove that $D(n_0)=n_0-3$).

Any diagonal cuts $n_0$-gon into $2$ parts:

- convex $j$-gon,
- convex $(n_0-j+2)$-gon.

($3\le j < n_0$).

Apply statement for $j$-gon and for $(n_0-j+2)$-gon separately.

You'll obtain:

$$
D(n_0) =  1+(j-3)+(n_0-j-1)=n_0-3.
$$

$\qquad \qquad$ [image: Polygon]